# Can you keyframe the aspect ratio of a camera?

Tags: camera, keyframes, resolution, multiresolution

I was wondering if there was any way to sort of keyframe the aspect ratio/ resolution of a camera, like from 1.85:1 to 2.39:1 in a single scene smoothly. Is something like that possible inside of blender or would I need to do this with separate clips and some editing?

Something similar to [this](https://www.tiktok.com/@clairdenoony/video/7205064383049878827?lang=en&q=clairdenoony&t=1679163839543).

Comment: No, you cannot change the ratio since a video file cannot contain different resolutions/aspect ratios in the same file. What is done in the reference is just adding black borders moving in from the top and bottom. This can of course be done in Blender or other video editing software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be more inclined to set that up in a video editor.  Since the desired end result seems to be displaying on a screen I'd just render the whole thing full frame and that'd give you more freedom to make fine adjustments and see the results real-time without rendering the whole thing out again.  Just animate some black bars on the sides or something.